# Simultaneously writing out an array while casting efficiently

Tags: arrays, file, casting, ostream

I have an array of `long double`s.  I want to write it out as an array of `double`s, however I don't want to create the `double` array first (I don't have the memory), and I'm worried about performance.

My (naive) solution:

```
 file.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
 if (file.is_open())
 {
    for (auto& i : out)
    {
        T2 ni = static_cast<T2>(i);
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&ni), static_cast<size_t>(sizeof(T2)));
    }
    file.close();
 }
```

However, for the arrays that I'm attempting to write out, I would be calling file.write 630,000,000 times (and since file.write creates a sentry object on each instantiation, this is expensive).  Is there a more efficient way to do this?